# Can't rename file using java

Tags: java, file, rename

I am currently trying to append some text onto the end of a file name using java but nothing seems to be happening. I have never used java to manipulate files before but going by posts online I've come up with this...

```
for (File f : fullFileList)
            {
                System.out.println(f.getName());
                if (moveToFailed(f))
                {
                    /*
                     * Moved to failed successfully
                     */
                    File newf= new File(f.getAbsolutePath() + ".processed");
                    f.renameTo(newf);

                }
            }
```

Can anyone help with this? 
Thanks!

(The file is being moved successfully so it is entering that loop)

Update:

```
boolean moveToFailed(File f) // Moves file to failed directory
{
    try
    {
        FileUtils.moveToDirectory(f, failedDirectory, true);
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Couldn't move " + f.getName()
                + " to failed directory!\n" + e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Please show the `moveToFailed()` function.

Comment: `renameTo` returns a `boolean` which may help you to determine if the call succeeded. You should also try to catch `SecurityException` for this operation.

Comment: Thanks - renameTo is returning false but there are no exceptions.

Comment: Where is `FileUtils` from?

Comment: FileUtils is part of the apache commons IO library

Comment: Can you confirm that `f.getAbsolutePath()` is what it's expected to be after the move but before the rename, and that a file `f.getAbsolutePath() + ".processed"` either doesn't exist or can be written/deleted? Depending on what system you're on, that could be determined either by permissions on the file itself or on the containing directory.

Comment: Hi iamnotmaynard. It appears as though getAbsolutePath is showing the old path and not the new path after the move. I can confirm that Java is able to create files so there are no permission issues here. Thanks

Comment: Ok, that's what I was wondering. It appears that `FileUtils.moveToDirectory()` moves the actual _file_ but doesn't change the path in the `File` object (I suppose this is because there's no access to that property). Oddly, from my tests it also looks like `f.renameTo(newf)` won't change the path in the object `f` either, though in that case you have `newf`, which represents the new path.

Answer (score -1):

```
String name = sourceFile.getName();
String dstName = name + ".processed";
File dest = new File(sourceFile.getParent(), dstName);
```

Comment: What is this supposed to do that OP's code doesn't do? Why would it make a difference?